# What should IS_SRVROLEMEMBER return for a domain user account that has been deleted?

Tags: sql-server

A Windows domain user account has been deleted because the person has left. However the account still exists on a SQL Server instance (I am going to delete it) and has sysadmin access.

If you query the account using `SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', 'DOMAIN\User.Name')` it returns a zero i.e. Indicating the account does not have sysadmin access. However if you query the `sys.server_principals` and `sys.server_role_members` views it is clear the account still has the sysadmin role. I also get the same result looking at the login properties via the SSMS GUI or running the PowerShell DBATools `Get-DbaServerRoleMember` command.

The login account has not been disabled on the instance. Looks the same as other existing sysadmin login as far as I can see.

In this case is the IS_SRVROLEMEMBER function working as expected? The online documentation does not seem to be clear (or I have mis-read it).

Comment: Well the user would not be able to even login to SQL Server because their account does not exist. Therefore they do not have sysadmin permissions. How is that incorrect? The only way this could possibly fail is if the user was still logged in and still had a valid Kerberos ticket, but if that's the case then all bets are off. Perhaps `Get-DbaServerRoleMember` should be changed to take that into account, maybe post a GitHub issue.

Comment: I did not say it was incorrect! I was asking whether it should be returning a zero, one or null in this situation. The reasoning behind it was if someone had a very large SQL estate and was doing some housekeeping in terms of looking for any existing granted sysadmin roles then this function does not look appropriate. I assume it does check with the domain server so see if the account is still valid which is fine but it should be made more clear.